# como cambiar los valores de una columna de un dataframe en pandas de 'Serial date' a date

Tags: python, pandas

mi consulta es que estoy leyendo un archivo de excel (xlsb) en pandas y a la hora de mostrar el dataframe, muestra las fechas como un numero entero (44423), haciendo busquedas me di cuenta que este es el numero de dias desde (1-1-1900), mi pregunta es como cambiar los valores de una columna del dataframe por las fechas en vez de el numero serial.

gracias

```
0         44409
1         44409
2         44409
3         44409
4         44409
```

y pasarlo a ***ej:*** `1/8/2021`

Answer (score 1):

Pandas incorpora la función `to_datetime()` que puede convertir fechas desde una gran variedad de formatos al formato `datetime`  usado por pandas.

En tu caso tienes que especificarle a esa función tu origen de tiempos (año 1900) y las unidades del contador (días), mediante los parámetros `origin="1900", unit="d"`.

Un ejemplo, dado un dataframe como el siguiente:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([44409, 44410, 44411, 44412], columns=["fecha"])
print(df)
```

---

```markdown
   fecha
0  44409
1  44410
2  44411
3  44412
```

La conversión se haría por ejemplo así:

```py
df.fecha = pd.to_datetime(df.fecha, origin="1900", unit="d")
print(df)
```

---

```markdown
       fecha
0 2021-08-03
1 2021-08-04
2 2021-08-05
3 2021-08-06
```